# Iterate on a html table with Selenium/Katalon

Tags: java, loops, selenium, html-table, katalon-studio

I'm trying to iterate through an HTML table to get values from it, but I do not get the desired results. This is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="o_sale_order table-responsive">
  <table class="o_list_view table table-sm table-hover table-striped o_list_view_ungrouped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="1" class="o_list_record_selector">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-868" class="custom-control-input">
            <label for="checkbox-868" class="custom-control-label"></label></div>
        </th>
        <th class="o_column_sortable" data-original-title="" title="">Quotation Number</th>
        <th class="o_column_sortable" data-original-title="" title="">Quotation Date</th>
        <th class="o_column_sortable" data-original-title="" title="">Customer</th>
        <th class="o_column_sortable" data-original-title="" title="">Salesperson</th>
        <th class="o_column_sortable" style="text-align: right;" data-original-title="" title="">Total</th>
        <th class="o_column_sortable" data-original-title="" title="">Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="ui-sortable">
      <tr class="o_data_row">
        <td width="1" class="o_list_record_selector">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-869" class="custom-control-input">
            <label for="checkbox-869" class="custom-control-label"></label></div>
        </td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_readonly_modifier o_required_modifier">SO107</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_required_modifier">03/04/2019 17:40:46</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_required_modifier">AA</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell">Administrator</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_list_number o_monetary_cell o_readonly_modifier">
          <span class="o_field_monetary o_field_number o_field_widget o_readonly_modifier" name="amount_total">305.00&nbsp;€</span></td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_readonly_modifier">Quotation Sent</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="o_data_row">
        <td width="1" class="o_list_record_selector">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-870" class="custom-control-input">
            <label for="checkbox-870" class="custom-control-label">​</label></div>
        </td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_required_modifier">SO055</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_required_modifier">03/01/2019 20:24:35</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_required_modifier">AA</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell">Administrator</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_list_number o_monetary_cell o_readonly_modifier">
          <span class="o_field_monetary o_field_number o_field_widget o_readonly_modifier" name="amount_total">2.44&nbsp;€</span></td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_readonly_modifier">Quotation</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="o_data_row">
        <td width="1" class="o_list_record_selector">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-871" class="custom-control-input">
            <label for="checkbox-871" class="custom-control-label">​</label></div>
        </td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_required_modifier">SO039</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_required_modifier">03/01/2019 12:16:08</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_required_modifier">AA</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell">Administrator</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_list_number o_monetary_cell o_readonly_modifier">
          <span class="o_field_monetary o_field_number o_field_widget o_readonly_modifier" name="amount_total">2.44&nbsp;€</span></td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_readonly_modifier">Quotation</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="o_data_row">
        <td width="1" class="o_list_record_selector">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-872" class="custom-control-input">
            <label for="checkbox-872" class="custom-control-label">​</label></div>
        </td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_required_modifier">SO025</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_required_modifier">02/28/2019 19:50:59</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_required_modifier">BB</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell">Administrator</td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_list_number o_monetary_cell o_readonly_modifier">
          <span class="o_field_monetary o_field_number o_field_widget o_readonly_modifier" name="amount_total">2.44&nbsp;€</span></td>
        <td class="o_data_cell o_readonly_modifier">Quotation</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="name"></td>
        <td class="date_order"></td>
        <td class="partner_id"></td>
        <td class="user_id"></td>
        <td class="amount_total o_list_number" title="Total Tax Included">312.32</td>
        <td class="state"></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</main>
</div>
```

I need to get from each row the value starting with "SO", like this:

```
<td class="o_data_cell o_required_modifier">SO055</td>
```

I tried with:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class = 'o_dropdown_toggler_btn btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle' and (contains(text(), 'Filters') or contains(., 'Filters'))]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Quotations')])[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class = 'o_dropdown_toggler_btn btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle' and (contains(text(), 'Filters') or contains(., 'Filters'))]")).click();

List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='o_list_view table table-sm table-hover table-striped o_list_view_ungrouped']//tr[not(th)]"));
        Iterator<WebElement> iter = rows.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            WebElement tr = iter.next();
            WebElement td = tr.findElement(By.xpath("./td[(@class='o_data_cell o_readonly_modifier o_required_modifier')]"));
            listaPreventiviFatturabili.add(td.getText());
        }
```

but it doesn't work.

This is a screenshot of the webpage in question:

[image: Screen]

Can you help me?

Another question: How can I wait for the page to load after I select the Filter for "Quotations"?

Comment: Concerning your second question: it depends. It is hard to tell without the HTML or knowing details about the page. What happens when you select the filter? You probably get some kind of spinner element. You can wait for it to be invisible.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The spinner doesn't disappear by itself, but remains open after selecting the filter. I think the only possibilities are to click again on "Filters" to close the spinner, in order to waste time waiting for the page to load, and wait for the "Quotations" filter to appear (clickable) inside the bar of research, but I do not know if it's enough. I do not think there are other possibilities because the rest of the page remains the same (no element appears or disappears), only the contents of the table are updated, which is not predictable. What do you think about it?

Comment: What is the expected behavior of the app when you click the "Filter"? From the end-user perspective?

Comment: The list normally contains both quotations and invoices, instead using one of the filters contained in the spinner "Filters" you can only view the quotations, which is what interests me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this xpath. It will return all cells containing SO value

```
By.xpath("//table//td[contains(text(),'SO')]");

List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//td[contains(text(),'SO')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly find all table cell in the first column where the `SOxxx` insides.

```
List<WebElement> first_cloumns = driver.findElements(
                     By.cssSelector("div.o_sale_order tbody td:nth-child(1)"));


List<String> values = first_cloumns
                            .stream() // require JDK 8 and higher
                            .map(td -> td.getText())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```